# I cant figure out how to use this function

Tags: autohotkey

I have been using [Polyethene's Command Functions](https://github.com/polyethene/AutoHotkey-Scripts/blob/master/Functions.ahk) library which is supposed to  act as a replacement for allot of commands, The AutoHotkey docs recommends the library [HERE](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Functions.htm#Other_Functions).  I have made use of it allot but I am struggling to make use of one function though, which is `GuiControlGet`, a replacement for the [GuiControlGet](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/GuiControlGet.htm) command.

In this example, I want to get the width of the `Text` control, I can find it with the `GuiControlGet` command but its  functional opposite fails with an error:

```
var := "Hello world"
Gui HUD:New, +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption +HwndMainHwnd, hudWin
Gui HUD:Font,s14,Consolas
Gui, Add, Text,,% var
GuiControlGet, OutputVar, Pos,% var
Gui HUD:Show, x300 y300 w300 h300

msgbox,% outputVarW                          ; returns the width of "Gui, Add, Text,,% var" control

OutPut := GuiControlGet("Pos", "var")   ; I get error: ==> Warning: This variable has not been assigned a value. Specifically: v  (a local variable)
msgbox,% OutPutW                                 ; Nothing shown

GuiControlGet(Subcommand = "", ControlID = "", Param4 = "") {
    GuiControlGet, v, %Subcommand%, %ControlID%, %Param4%
    Return, v
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way:

```
Global v  ; <---
var := "Hello world"
Gui HUD:New, +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption +HwndMainHwnd, hudWin
Gui HUD:Font,s14,Consolas
Gui, Add, Text,,% var
; Gui HUD:Show, x300 y300 w300 h300
GuiControlGet("Pos", var)   ; <--- var cant be between double quotes
msgbox % vw "`n"
       . vh "`n"
       . vx "`n"
       . vy 
GuiControlGet(Subcommand = "", ControlID = "", Param4 = "") {

    GuiControlGet, v, %Subcommand%, %ControlID%, %Param4%
    Return, v

}
```

Or this...

```
var := "Hello world"
Gui HUD:New, +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption +HwndMainHwnd, hudWin
Gui HUD:Font,s14,Consolas
Gui, Add, Text,,% var
; Gui HUD:Show, x300 y300 w300 h300
MsgBox  % GuiControlGet("Pos", var)["w"] "`n"
        . GuiControlGet("Pos", var)["h"] "`n"
        . GuiControlGet("Pos", var)["x"] "`n"
        . GuiControlGet("Pos", var)["y"]

;   Another way
    output:= GuiControlGet("Pos", var)
    MsgBox  % output["w"] "`n"
            . output["h"] "`n"
            . output["x"] "`n"
            . output["y"]

GuiControlGet(Subcommand = "", ControlID = "", Param4 = "") {

    Params := {w : 0, h : 0, x : 0, y : 0 }
    GuiControlGet, v, %Subcommand%, %ControlID%, %Param4%
    for value, i in params
        params[value] := v%value%

    Return params

}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Cheers!